# Kernel of a matrix using the rref of its transpose

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the most elegant way to calculate a basis for the kernel of a matrix $$
if one has already calculated the row reduced echelon form of its transpose $^T$
? Can one avoid further row reductions or matrix inversions?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There is a nice approach if you also know what exactly the row-operations were to obtain the rref

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that works if we have access to the row-operations used to obtain the rref of $A^T$ (or equivalently, if we have the rref of the augmented matrix $[A^T \mid I]$, where $I$ denotes the identity matrix).

Suppose that $R$ is the rref of $A^T$ and that the elementary matrices $E_1,\dots,E_k$ are such that $E_k\cdots E_1 A^T = R$. Let $E = E_k \cdots E_1$, so that $EA^T = R$ (alternatively, obtain $E$ with $[A^T \mid I] \to [R \mid E]$). Partition $R$ so that
$$
R = \pmatrix{R_0\\ 0},
$$
where $R_0$ has no zero-rows. Partition $E$ into
$$
E = \pmatrix{E_1\\E_2},
$$
where $E_1$ has the same number of rows as $R_0$. Note that
$$
EA^T = R \implies \pmatrix{E_1\\E_2}A^T = \pmatrix{R_0\\0} \implies \\
E_1A^T = R_0, \quad E_2A^T = 0\implies\\
AE_1^T = R_0^T, \quad AE_2^T = 0.
$$
With that, we can conclude that the columns of $E_2^T$ form a basis for the kernel of $A$.

Comment: That is at least something. The good thing about it is that one only needs an echelon form. I am still wondering about the original question. Thank you for sharing this.

Comment: @HCH The rref of $A^T$ is not enough on its own to determine the kernel of $A$. The problem is that row operations, while they maintain the kernel, do not maintain the kernel of the transpose

Comment: Hello Ben, I elaborated the idea further. Check out sections 8 and 9 in https://hal.science/hal-04091017. The method is quite practical now. Thanks for sharing your idea.